# Strange Swagger behavior

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, openapi

I have the following API model class:

```
public class CarrierDomainApi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Domain name
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>domain.com</example>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "domainName")]
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
}
```

and WebAPI method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domain"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Authorize(Roles = "CompanyAdministrators")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1-companyadmin")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]string domain)
    {
        return Created(string.Empty, null);
    }
```

with `string` parameter it generates correct swagger page, but if I change to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]CarrierDomainApi domain)
```

I get a standard swagger error, if something is going wrong:

> Failed to load API definition.

[image]

what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please add ```app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();``` in Configure() method to get more detailed information about the error? This will provide you useful direction!

Comment: the same error without detail information